# Looping through a dataset

Tags: c#

I'm looping through the rows and columns of a DataSet to write to a text file with a pipe delimiter.  I have it working except I need to leave off the pipe from the last column.   Is there a way for me to adjust the loop to loop through fields.count-1 and then refer to the last field outside of the loop?

```
foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
{
    d = d+ item.ToString() + "|";
}
```

Comment: `String.Join("|",row.ItemArray) `?

Comment: Do you have null values in the rows you are looping over?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos add an answer.  It's better than the other two already added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can join the contents of any IEnumerable (including arrays) using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx), eg:

```
var newText = String.Join("|",row.ItemArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq Aggregate:

```
d = row.ItemArray.Aggregate((x, y) => x.ToString() + "|" + y.ToString());
```

Comment: How is this simpler than String.Join()? Not being pedantic, just asking if there's some issue with String.Join().

Comment: There isn't, I just hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Gotcha. It seems like LINQ really can do everything. :)

Comment: http://devlifeasis.blogspot.com/2012/10/stringjoin-vs-linqaggregate.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TrimEnd(Char[])` method like

```
d.TrimEnd(new char[]{'|'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
string.Join("|", row.ItemArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `string.Join` method, as follows:

```
string.Join("|", row.ItemArray);
```

However, if you're doing other logic in the `foreach` loop as well, consider using a `StringBuilder` instead.  This has huge performance gains over concatenating a string over and over again. Then, you can simply trim off the final pipe by adjusting it's length.

```
var d = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
     d.Append(item.ToString()).Append("|");

d.Length -= 1;
```

Comment: There is no need to call `ToString()` or `ToArray()`

Comment: Yea, for some reason I always thought I needed to pass only a `string[]` in, I've updated my answer.

Comment: IEnumerable support was added in 4.0 I think. Took me a couple of years to realize this too. I think I realized it looking through SO questions ...

Comment: `String.Join` uses a `StringBuilder` under the hood.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Comment: `String.Join` might use it under the hood, but if he needs to do other logic on the `item` (and edited it out in the question for brevity) - my point still stands :)

Answer (score 0):

after the loop:

```
d = d.remove(d.Count()-1);
```

This will remove the last character of your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i ++)
{
    if(row.ItemArray[i] == row.itemArray[row.itemArray - 1])
    {
        d = d+ item.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
    d = d+ item.ToString() + "|";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add a delimiter if your adding another value.

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i ++)
{
    if( d.length == 0)
    {
        d = item.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        d = d + "|" + item.ToString();
    }
}
```